# Eclipse IDE: Using Find references only shows the first occurrence of a variable in a file

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I execute the Find References command in the Eclipse Platform
Version 3.4.1, this outputs only the first occurrence of the variable in the project file:

[image]

How to make it so that in the Eclipse Platform version
Version 3.4.1 output all occurrences of a variable?

When running this command in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857 displays all occurrences of the variable as a list:

[image]

I need a version of Eclipse Platform to work
Version 3.4.1.

Comment: Eclipse 3.4 is 15 years and 30 releases old, nothing recent is going to run with that and nobody is going to remember anything about what such an ancient release could do. Why are you running such old code?

Comment: This is because I am using an Eclipse distribution that contains the Nios II Software Build Tools for Eclipse. I can not use a newer version of this assembly yet

Comment: You're confusing the following things: Stack Overflow is not [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 contained the Eclipse Platform 3.7.2, not 3.4.1, and the _Find References_ command is not part of the Eclipse Platform, but of CDT or the Eclipse-based application/distribution you have. Better fix your root problem instead of wasting everyone's time with retrocomputing.